# Python write to MySQL - no error but no writing

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am trying to write into my localhost MySQL database.

I have created a database named "test", a table called "price_update" and a row called "model"

When I run the script below I get no errors, however, I also get nothing written to my database.

I am not sure where to start looking for the problem. the row is varchar(10) and collation utf9_general_ci.

```
import MySQLdb

conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="someUser",passwd="somePassword",db="test")

query = "INSERT INTO price_update (model) values ('12345')"
x = conn.cursor()
x.execute(query)
row = x.fetchall()
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to commit the changes:

```
conn.commit()
```

Also, I'd make your query safer:

```
query = "INSERT INTO price_update (model) values (%s)"
...
x.execute(query, ('12345',))
```

Comment: Does conn.commit() go at the end of the script?

Comment: @Travis: You could put it after `x.execute(query)`.